# Requirejs Angular and TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, typescript

I am using angular + requirejs, and want to make it work with typescript.
How can i write this script in typescript?

**HomeController1.js**

```
define(['controllers/controllers'],
    function (controllers) {
        controllers.controller('HomeController',
            ['$window',
            '$scope',
    function (
        $window,
        $scope) {

        $scope.showSubRouting = true;

        }

    ]);
});
```

**Controllers1.js**

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    return angular.module('controllers', []);
});
```

I tried this :

HomeController2.ts

```
 import controllers = require("controllers/controllers");

     class HomeController {

        showSubRouting: boolean = false
        constructor() {

        }


    }
```

Controllers2.ts

```
import angular = require("angular");

angular.module("controllers", []);
```

**but** controller's definition is missing in HomeController2.js
(`define(['controllers/controllers']`)

HomeController2.js

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
        var HomeController = (function () {
            function HomeController() {
                this.showSubRouting = false;
            }
            return HomeController;
        })();
    });
```

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Controllers2.ts

You need to export what you want to import elsewhere. So:

```
import angular = require("angular");

export var controllerModule = angular.module("controllers", []);
```